# How can I plot an implicit function?

Tags: plotting

Say I have a function

How can I plot the following function

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look up the documentation for `ContourPlot`.

Comment: I imagine you want the full heart. You can use the real-valued cube root instead of the principal valued one: `ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - CubeRoot[x]^2)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 2}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the suggestion of @march:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - x^(2/3))^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you are more comfortable with the use of `Plot`:

```
Plot[Flatten@Solve[x^2 + (y - x^(2/3))^2 == 1, y][[;; , ;; , 2]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Flatten` is not necessary in `Plot` as they formulas aren't to deep, but if you want to see where it transitions from one solution to the other, you can replace it with `Evaluate`.

Comment: I think the OP meant something like `ContourPlot[{x^2 + (y - x^(2/3))^2 ==   1, (-x)^2 + (y - (-x)^(2/3))^2 == 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 2}, 
 ContourStyle -> Red]`? (+1)

Comment: Thanks for helping me ... excellent answer @Marchi

Comment: Thanks for helping me ... excellent answer @rcollyer

Comment: Thanks for helping me ... excellent answer @kglr